# libwebsockets lib with openssl for iOS crashes in SSL_CTX_new()

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl, websocket, openssl

I am trying to use libwebsockets (http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets) library for websockets support in my app. I need it to be secure so I am trying to build it with openssl lib which I've built using https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/blob/master/build-libssl.sh script. CMake creates libwebsockets project which I slightly modify to use static openssl library. Then I add this project to my workspace and build my app. App is built without problems. When I launch it and try to establish websocket connection I get crash in SHA1_Final function while I try to create new context using SSL_CTX_new().

[image: Crash backtrace]

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x000fa47e MyApp`SHA1_Final + 22, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x22986341)
frame #0: 0x000fa47e MyApp`SHA1_Final + 22
frame #1: 0x00130a90 MyApp`EVP_DigestFinal_ex + 56
frame #2: 0x0012e45c MyApp`ssleay_rand_add + 492
frame #3: 0x0012f056 MyApp`RAND_poll + 614
frame #4: 0x0012e726 MyApp`ssleay_rand_bytes + 166
frame #5: 0x000ef49c MyApp`SSL_CTX_new + 464
frame #6: 0x00153218 MyApp`libwebsocket_create_context(info=0x2fda90bc) + 1364 at libwebsockets.c:1975
```

I also have nss library (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS) and a bunch of other security related files which is needed for other libraries in my project.

I have tried to create simple test project with one view and only libwebsockets and openssl library in it and in that project openssl doesn't crash.

I guess that the problem I have is related either to existence of nss and openssl libraries in the same project or to possible different compile settings for openssl and other projects.  (And yes, I've checked, libwebsockets lib calls SSL_library_init()).

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please let me know how you "slightly modify to use static openssl library" ? libwebsockets w/ ssl works fine when run from xcode, but when distrod via TestFlight (and I assume appstore) I get a crash. I think it's trying to use dynamic libs. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,I am trying to compile libwebsocket library for iOS, But i am facing problem "CMake Error at toolchain/iOS.cmake:101 (message):
  No iOS SDK's found in default seach path
  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer.  Manually set
  CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT or install the iOS SDK." please give me some hint how did you compile libwebsocket library for iOS

Comment: @Mahesh Well, CMAKE already has given you hint. You either don't have iOS SDK or you have some troubles with your paths.

Comment: we have iOS Sdk path in mac and i had given manually also by using command   cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$HOME/out/ios -DCMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/ios-cmake/toolchain/iOS.cmake -GXcode

Comment: @Mahesh I believe this is worth a separate questions. Try to check what paths CMAKE checks for SDK and compare to where SDK really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I have nailed down the problem.

NSS library has SHA1 functions which has the same names that openssl has. I don't completely understand why linker didn't complain about duplicate symbols but the problem was that openssl was using one of SHA1 functions from NSS and all the others from openssl. By doing that ssl context was being corrupted by wrong function from NSS and then crashing in openssl function.

I would appreciate some thoughts why linker let it all compile but moving all the app to use only openssl solved my problem.

Comment: What function did you have to change?? Would be good info for others reading this :)

Comment: @braden As I wrote in my answer, I had 2 ssl libraries (NSS and openssl) linked to my app which both have SHA1 function with the same name. Linker didn't complain about duplicate symbols but in runtime incorrect function was used which led to crashes.

Comment: @braden Just to clarify: I ended up removing openssl in favour of NSS for that project.

Comment: Maybe, linker didn't complain to you because you didn't set -all_load linker flag. In this case all duplicate architecture symbols will be noted.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reason behind that, `-objC` from other linker flag allow to import all the objective c categories from static library and here it conflicts with openssl. if you remove that flag then it will take openssl for linking.